# register_globals is enabled. Drupal requires this configuration directive to be disabled

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've just moved my drupal to a new server and I get the following warning:

register_globals is enabled. Drupal requires this configuration directive to be disabled. Your site may not be secure when register_globals is enabled. The PHP manual has instructions for how to change configuration settings. (Currently using PHP register globals Enabled ('1'))

Should I change the configuration of the php server or I can ignore it ?
I probably don't have access to php settings.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with your host if they can help you out. If you don't have access to php.ini then you may not be able to. register_globals has been off for a good number of years now so that's surprising. If the host allows you .htaccess files you can add this to yours:

```
php_flag register_globals off
```

Comment: I've actually added these lines to .htaccess but it doesn't solve the issue... http://it.php.net/configuration.changes

Comment: Since register_globals has been off by default for 10 years now (since php 4.2.0), I would be worried which php version your host is running. If it's php4, I would definitely start looking for another host.

Comment: Yeah, your host should fix this for you, and everyone else they're hosting. It's pretty irresponsible that they've left register_globals on.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly hostgator leaves them enabled :(

Sometimes making the change in .htaccess is not sufficient. Hostgator has a little elaborate process and it can be irritating some times.

You will need to add the default `php.ini` file that Hostgator provides to your root. And then add the `.htaccess` with an entry for the address of `php.ini` to the www doc root.

For detailed steps and downloading these docs(`php.ini and .htaccess` file)read my blog on [How to turn off register_globals in hostgator](http://www.drupaltonight.com/drupal-articles/how-turn-registerglobals-hostgator)

Comment: Thanks, I was just having this issue with HostGator!

Comment: This did worked. In fact, in hostgator's knowledge base they actually explain how to do it: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/register-globals-and-other-php-settings

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on a forum.

So just just edit the file / / modules / system system.install then go to line 56:

```
$requirements['php_register_globals']['severity'] = REQUIREMENT_ERROR;
```

and replaced by:

```
$requirements['php_register_globals']['severity'] = REQUIREMENT_WARNING;
```

Well, that's all, the installation should run perfectly normally.

As for me I think I'll go back nuked klan too uzinagaz this CMS ...